# disable all windows that are related with the current application

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

I have a main app that is able to call .net methods. My .net method starts a new thread that shows a modal form.

Now my .net method needs to disable all windows from the main app while the modal form is shown.

How can I do this?

I was thinking about the win32 method "GetWindow",, but then I would need the handle of the main-app form.

In my example you see the main app that calls the method with the modal dialog.
When I click on the main app while the threadingform-dlg is open, the threadingform-dlg should blink.

[image: main app with modal dialog]

Comment: The best solution would be for the main app to pass its window handle to the .net method. Then there is no guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (Form openedForm in Application.OpenForms) {
    if (openedForm.GetType() == FormToClose) {
        openedForm.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thats great. but how do i "flash" the threadingform if the disabled mainform is clicked? is there a way without adding an onclick event?

Comment: @wuhi: The *blinking* should me automatic if you open the threading form with `ShowDialog`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ShowDialog()` function of the form instead of `Show()`. It will automatically make the form modal.

I don't know if it disables all other windows or only the calling one, try.

Comment: actually im using showmodal. but its not exactly what i want.
if i click the buttons of the main app, they are getting pressed after the modal dialog gets closed. :(

Comment: That will have no effect, since the form is being shown from a separate thread.

Answer (score 3):

You should not show a modal form from a separate thread (you really shouldn't even show a non-modal form from a thread). Instead, display the modal form from your application's main form. If this requires moving some of your code around, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the all open windows of the application by accessing [OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property.

```
var forms = Application.OpenForms;
```